# The science behind Squall's Gunblade, if there is any?

Tags: final-fantasy

So, Revolver, Squall's gunblade, is a pure melee weapon, and not actually a gun. Apparently, squeezing the trigger just before the blade hits the target mid-swing amplifies the damage dealt by this weapon.

Here's what I know, and please correct me if I am wrong:

- It uses cartridges (most likely, without the bullet/projectile part) to do its damage-amplification thing.

And here are my issues:

- Since making the cartridges explode is the key to the damage-amplification mechanism, does the explosion send vibrations to the blade, like star wars' vibro blades?
- Or does it use the raw explosion, like, making mini shockwaves to deal more damage?
- Either way, do you think there is a barrel (with only one hole, since the tip of the Revolver has no hole, like for bullets) inside for this vibration/shockwave to travel to the blade?
- Asuming that there exist a material elastic and strong enough to do this mechanism, do you think it would make sense scientifically?
- Do you have some more ideas to share?

[image: Squall's Revolver]

Comment: You might find [this question on Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/53359/6992) of interest.

Answer (score 5):

After reading the information on [Gunblade wiki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Gunblade_(weapon_type)), Squall's - and Seifer's - Gunblades do contain a barrel that runs through the sword. When the trigger is pulled, it emits a shockwave that deals additional damage when it strikes the enemy.

> In Final Fantasy VIII gunblades have a sword blade with a gun action built into the hilt, the barrel running inside the length of the blade. They are mostly used like normal swords, but triggering a round sends a shockwave through the blade as the weapon passes through an opponent to boost damage

The reason behind this design was that Tetsuya Nomura was looking for something to further engage the players.

> The gunblade was designed by Tetsuya Nomura for Squall's weapon in Final Fantasy VIII with the aim to make the battles more dynamic, the players needing to press a button at the correct time to deal a critical hit, and to give Squall an iconic weapon.

Seeing how this was the first game in game franchise to use the style of weapon, it is no surprise there were some design flaws in the implementation.

Furthermore, later games in the franchise still use Gunblades and they expanded on this style of weapon to allow both shooting and slicing

Answer (score 2):

Some sort of blank round most likely, a ten gauge round half full of powder would have a recoil like a 12 gauge. Also all the unburnt powder would make an explosion like that seen in game, and the primer going off would provide the noise. Without projectile = less recoil and noise per gram of powder. As for the powder, probably a custom mix that would resemble pyrotechnic powders.
Also: all it needs is a twelve gauge barrels strength and you are good to go.
Although the recoil would force the gun back lightly. The weapon is so overbuilt that the overall recoil would be low, as it is many times heavier than even the most overbuilt 12 gauge. Heavier weapon frame=less recoil.

Answer (score 0):

I belive people are over thinking the idea if the "barell" simply curves upward the recoil would assist swining the sword downward side to side ect